Prove that the operator is diagonalizable
I need help finding the source or an idea to solve the following problem:
Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$, and $L:V\to V$ is an operator. Assume that the following two conditions are satisfied:

$|\lambda|=1$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $L$.
$||L(x)||\leq ||x||$ for all $x\in V$, where $||x||=\sqrt{(x,x)}$.

Prove that $L$ is diagonalizable.

Are you familiar with the Schur decomposition?

This is Problem 9 from Chapter 7, Section D in Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (4th edition)
Hint: Use the Schur decomposition theorem to obtain an orthonormal basis to which $L$ has an upper-triangular matrix. Then use the 2nd condition to show that the upper-triangular matrix is also symmetric, hence $L$ is diagonalizable.

Looks like the problem is a Schur thing.

Thank you! I don't know if the friend who was trying to solve this already discussed Schur in class, but I'll let him know.

This also follows very quickly from Hadamard's inequality.
